# Basic NIS questions

Tags: nis

I'm a software developer who finds himself the SA stuckee when one SA went on vacation right after the other one quit. We have a network of redhat/solaris machines with a solaris NIS server. I want to create local accounts for an sftp server on the network without granting network accounts. I also want to create a local group specific to these accounts to manage access.

How do I keep the network and local group IDs and user IDs from conflicting with the NIS IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How do I keep the network [NIS] and local [/etc] group IDs and user IDs from conflicting [...]?**

With a clipboard.
Alternatively, by keeping all NIS UID/GID numbers above a certain value (say 10000) and all local UIDs/GIDs below that value.

I strongly suggest you speak to your system administrator before mucking about with the environment. They will probably be a little ticked off at being called on vacation, but they will certainly be **seriously displeased** with you if you create a mess that they have to unwind when they return - especially if said mess creates UID/GID overlaps inadvertently, and/or requires re-jiggering ownerships and permissions on lots of files.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. Unfortunately our SA isn't reachable, and, in any case, he's been more focused on the windows network and isn't really up to speed on nis administration yet. We no doubt have some painful learning coming up.

Comment: In that case the duty of making the clipboard falls to you as the first poor bastard to touch the environment :-)